# picture quality is lost after updating

Tags: android

I am building an Android App Bundle, and the image quality disappears after updating via google play console. I test the quality before loading, after passing the test I load the picture of a different quality. What is this, tell me what to do.
I download PNG, even in the preview in android studio, the quality disappears. 16 bit color linear solid.
16 bit.
Integer.
Quality is lost.
I load 8 bit image quality is not lost.
This means that android studio does not support high resolution resources.

Comment: could you add samples to show that, before and after upload to Google Store?

Comment: Did you put your image both in the drawable and drawable-v24 folders?

Comment: No, I can't show it yet.
put in a folder drawable-xxxhdpi

Comment: Tell me where to put high-resolution images in drawable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to make the format PNG as JPG sometimes does not retain its quality on Android when modified.

Comment: Not sure i can understand what you meant by that. Could you clarify please?

Comment: I download PNG, even in the preview in android studio, the quality disappears. 16 bit color linear solid.